# Изоляция виртуальной машины в сети

Tags: windows, сеть, виртуальная-машина, vlan

Приветствую. 
Возникла следующая ситуация:
в сети есть сервер с linux и есть пк с windows, на котором запущена виртмашина.
Задача: нужно организовать связь между сервером и виртмашиной, но так, чтобы виртмашина была изолирована от остальных устройств.
Моё решение: добавить vlan и вынести в него виртмашину, а на сервере просто поднять второй интерфейс с этим вланом.
Проблема: windows не умеет vlan. Можно настроить в сетевой карте vlanid, но в таком случае весь трафик пойдет в этот vlan. Специальной утилиты для atheros я не нашел.

Есть ли иные варианты, как можно ограничить доступ виртмашине?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но может подойдёт NAT?